# use union in sparql query

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia

I've got this SPARQL query between 2 DBpedia resources: France and Alstom

```
select * where{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/France> ?pre ?obj.

?obj ?pre1 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alstom>
}
```

and it returns nothing

but if I reverse the subject and the object like this:

```
select * where{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alstom> ?pre ?obj.
?obj ?pre1 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/France>
}
```

the query returns some results..

[SPARQL Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20where%7B%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAlstom%3E%20%3Fpre%20%3Fobj.%0D%0A%3Fobj%20%3Fpre1%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFrance%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

is there any way to merge the two queries using UNION?

Comment: What is the purpose? When it is empty, what do you want to achieve by writing a union? The union is just going to return the set that is full. I don't really understand this question.

Comment: I wanna satisfy if there is a relation between two resources, the first query shows that there is not, but the second one shows that there is!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you just need a straightforward union with the following syntax:

```
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
select * where{
{
    dbpedia:France ?pre ?obj.
    ?obj ?pre1 dbpedia:Alstom.
}
Union {
    dbpedia:Alstom ?pre ?obj.
?obj ?pre1 dbpedia:France
}
}
```